# How to convert a bytes string to unicode value to display emoji in Java?

Tags: java, unicode, emoji

I used the `pepibumur/emojize` in web project, not Android or iOS.

The project defined the relationship with unicode and word, so I must find the emoji string and convert to unicode.

the emoji unicode table like that `http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode`.

I already get the byte string like that `\xf0\x9f\x9a\x92`.

But I didn't know how to convert to the unicode `U+1F692`, How to convert? Thank  you!

Answer (score 3):

To convert from UTF-8 bytes you need:

```
String s = new String(new byte[]{(byte) 0xF0, (byte) 0x9F, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0x81}, "UTF-8");
```

But it's too complex, and I recommend to use value from `Surrogates` column:

```
String s = "\uD83D\uDE4C";
```